# Cannot retrieve images from Mysql to show on html menu section

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am working on an e-commerce website and I'm having trouble displaying images from mysql database to be rendered in my html products section, as a newbie to programming, I'd like this explained to me in the most easiest way possible, here is my html loop that is in charge of displaying the images from mysql.

```
<div class="row special-list">
        <% result.forEach(function(product) { %>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 special-grid best-seller">
          <div class="products-single fix">
            <div class="box-img-hover">
              <div class="why-text">
                <h4><%= product.name %></h4>
                <h5>Ksh <%= product.price %>.00</h5>
                <form id="add-to-cart-form-<%= product.id %>" class="add-to-cart-form" data-product-id="<%= product.id %>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<%= product.id %>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<%= product.name %>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="<%= product.price %>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_sale_price" value="<%= product.sale_price %>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_quantity" value="1" min="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_image" value="<%= product.image %>">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart-button" data-product-id="<%= product.id %>">Add to Cart</button>
                </form>
                <div class="add-to-cart-success-message" style="display: none;">
                  Item added to the cart
                </div>
              </div>
              <img src="/images/<%= product.image%>.jpg" alt="<%= product.name %>">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
      </div>
```

I have tried setting up static file to use my public folder in my server:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Here is where my image is hosted and this is the link I have in mysql database:
`http://localhost/images/blog-img-02.jpg`